# Launch images for app with variable initial screen

Tags: ios

What is the best practice for generating launch images for apps where the initial screen varies?

Previously I've used screenshotting in the simulator to generate launch images. However the app I'm working on now displays one of two completely different screens depending on whether the user has set-up an account with a cloud service. There is no commonality between the two screens.

Should I just display a completely empty image, one that is blank except for an empty navigation bar, or something else? I considered a logo but the HIG warns against splash screens.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do much if you are using images (xcasset-based, or otherwise), however starting with iOS 8 you can configure a *Launch Screen File*, which uses a `.xib` or storyboard file to provide the launch image, which means you could probably build logic into that to display conditional content.  Not that I've ever done it myself, mind...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can see how using a storyboard launch screen file helps to avoid having multiple launch images for different files/orientations. But I would need to run some code to determine which screen to display, and that doesn't seem to be possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AndyJohnson Yeah I haven't actually done it myself and I'm unsure what Apple's recommendation is WRT processing that should take place during the display process (I would imagine it's "Don't do anything").  I think this is your only avenue, however.

Comment: Looks like its not possible to run custom code in the launch screen storyboard. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27642160/67316 and http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/