# How to let user customize LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

In my app I want a user to be able to choose a background image. Imagine it something like the background image you can choose for your WhatsApp Chat.

To make a smooth start, I would like the Launchscreen to display exactly that image. The User would see his/her background image and the user interface would just fade in when the app is finished loading.

Obviously that would mean I have to manipulate the LaunchScreen.storyboard at runtime which isn't possible.

My idea was to save the choses background in a file and let the imageView in the LaunchScreen.storyboard use a path instead of an image. Unfortunately I have no idea how I could do that. Is my idea possible?

I'm using Swift 2 for my iOS app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642016/execute-code-in-launch-screen/27642160#27642160

Comment: Hi, MikeyB, I think it's not possible currently because storyboard looks at images that reside in the bundle of your app, and you have no possibility to change (add/edit) files in the bundle at runtime. But you can make 2-step launch screen presentation, for example, add simple LaunchStoryboard, and make your app startup time as quicker as you can, and after app is loaded, present second, user-customized screen for a second