# Execute Code in Launch Screen UPDATED

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

[Execute Code in Launch Screen ORIGINAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642016/execute-code-in-launch-screen)

Now that the default `LaunchScreen` file in Xcode projects have been changed from `.xib` to `.storyboard` files (just like `Main.storyboard`), is it now possible to design the launch screen programmatically if you choose to?

Can you write custom code for the launch screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to write any custom class/code for the launchscreen xib/storyboard files. We can only design using resource files.

Answer (score 2):

Completely Agree with [Arun Ammannaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5746309/arun-ammannaya). I ran a test to verify it and here is the result.

[image: Can't add custom class to Launch Screen]

Comment: Presumably I can assume the same result would occur with Swift?

Answer (score -2):

**Yes, its possible to write ViewController for the launch screen,**

**1)** Create viewController file, create Xib for the same.

**2)** In the RootViewController's (say HomeViewController or SignInViewController) ViewDidLoad(),

**2a)** Create object of SplashViewController.

**2b)** Add view of splashViewController to your HomeViewController.

```
let objSplashVC = yourCode to create object of SplashVC
self.view.addSubView(objSplashVC.view);
```

**c)** After 2 or 3 seconds or once your retrieve data on Web-Service call, you can remove that view, by calling hide() method of SplashViewController

```
hide(){
       self.view.removeFromSuperView();
   }
```

**Note : You have to add background image on SplashViewController as same as launchImage. So transitions will go smoothly.**

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for. This presents a splash view controller after the app is launched and the launch screen has been shown. The OP wants the launch screen done with code.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I agree, although it is a sneaky workaround and may be useful in specific app designs - it isn't really an answer to my question.