# how to execute code on startup(show) window from xib/nib in swift

Tags: swift, macos, xcode8-beta6

I have made a window.xib file and I would like to execute some code when et starts up (shows) like applicationDidFinishLaunching in main window.

how do I do that in Swift OS X .

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible to run any code on Launch Screen.**

Please take a look at this answer: [Execute code in Launch Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642016/execute-code-in-launch-screen)