# Is rootViewController always ready to present a segue by the time application:didBecomeActive is called (iOS)?

Tags: ios, loading, rootviewcontroller

My app has a rootViewController setup in a storyboard. I originally asked this question, but I can see that it is the wrong question to ask now:

> Is the `viewDidLoad` method of the rootViewController always called
>   before `application:didBecomeActive` in the app delegate? Does that
>   `viewDidLoad` method always finish before
>   `application:didBecomeActive` is called, or can the two run
>   concurrently?
>
> I can run tests, but I know that these tests don't take into account
>   every situation. I want to understand if there are hard and fast rules
>   that apply here, or if I might possibly be dealing with race
>   conditions at some point. From what I can tell, `viewDidLoad` of the
>   rootViewController seems to be called and finished before
>   `application:didbecomeActive` is called, but I can't figure out if
>   this is something I can rely on.
>
> I am using iOS 11 and Xcode 9.

My rootViewController serves to show my appUpdating view, passcode view, my legal terms view, my handleImportedFile view, and my tabbarcontroller. It is like a launch coordinator of sorts, because my loading process is extremely complicated. Now I am moving the location of the user's sqlite database, and some of my user's databases are huge. It has to be done in the background, but while a hud is running on the main queue, because the app cannot show data until this is done. If I do this during `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, some users are getting the watchdog timer. So I want to move the loading process to `application:didBecomeActive` (I have a flag to tell me if app is launching from terminated). When it is done running, the rootViewController performs a segue to the pertinent view. But I think rootViewController needs to have loaded by that time, and I am not sure that that is always the case.

Basically, in the code below, I am trying to figure out if `[self.masterController showApplicableView]`, which causes the rootViewController (which I call masterController) to perform a segue, is called in a 'safe place', or if, in *any* case, it could possibly be too early to have the rootViewController perform a segue at this point.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.masterController = (MasterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    self.activatingFromTerminated = YES;

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    self.activatingFromTerminated = NO;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    if (_activatingFromTerminated) {

        self.activatingFromTerminated = NO;

        [[CoreDataController sharedManager] loadStoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if ([CoreDataController sharedManager].storeLoaded) {

                [self.masterController showApplicableView];//performs applicable segue
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want/need to rely on this?

Comment: It has to do with the watchdog timer. Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: They can't run concurrently since both run on the main queue.

Comment: Sorry about not formatting the methods. So I put a sleepForTimeInterval: of 100 in the viewDidLoad of the rootViewController and application:didBecomeActive wasn't called until it was done running. But that still doesn't tell me if application:didbecomeActive *can* be called before the rootViewController's viewDidLoad, right?

Comment: Honestly, if you think you need to know this then you are probably doing something you shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I can tell, viewDidLoad of the rootViewController seems to be called and finished before application:didbecomeActive is called, but I can't figure out if this is something I can rely on.

It isn’t and you shouldn’t. You shouldn’t be concerned about this at all. The fact that you think you need to know this is a Bad Smell in your code. These are lifetime events from two completely different areas (the app and a view controller) and their relative timing should be no concern of yours. Do in each what is appropriate to the meaning of that event.

Comment: My rootViewController serves to show my appUpdating view, passcode view, my legal terms view, my handleImportedFile view, and my tabbarcontroller. It is like a launch coordinator of sorts, because my loading process is extremely complicated. Now I am moving sqlite database locations from documents to application support directory, and some of my user's databases are huge. It has to be done while a hud is running on the main queue, because the app cannot show data until this is done. If I do this during application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, some users are getting the watchdog timer.

Comment: So I want to move the process to application:didBecomeActive (I have a flag to tell me if app is launching from terminated). And when it is done running, tell the rootViewController to load the pertinent view.

Comment: I get what you are saying, I just do not know of a better way to handle this complex loading process and moving and doing a lightweight migration on large database, all at startup. Would love thoughts on how to better accomplish if I am approaching in the wrong way.

Comment: “Would love thoughts on how to better accomplish if I am approaching in the wrong way” Sure, but that wasn’t what you asked. You’ve basically totally changed what the question is.

Comment: It's hard to win on StackOverflow... I actually only wanted the answer to my initial question, but everyone wanted to know why because of bad code smell. I tried to explain why, so that maybe someone might say - no, actually that is a valid thing to do (if it is) - and I can proceed to try to find the answer. But seems like you are saying that it IS bad code and affirming your original answer. I get it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Well, there’s really only one thing in your revision that means anything to me: “some users are getting the watchdog timer”. The meaning of that is very clear. You are doing time consuming work on the main thread. Stop doing that immediately.

Comment: Main thread is the hud running in the foreground while LARGE database is backed up and moved to a new location, lightweight migration is performed, and version updates are run - all in the background

Comment: But there should not be a “hud running”. You can say whatever you like, but the watchdog means you are delaying launch, accidentally or deliberately. Maybe you think you can  “wait” for the background work to get done. That is the same as doing that work on the main thread. You need to get off the main thread immediately. Then all this order of events stuff will cease to matter.

Comment: Watch any of the performance or launch videos from WWDC over the past two or three years. The rules are very clear.

Comment: Right - which is why I am trying to move all of the loading from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to application:didBecomeActive (with a flag set in that method to tell if the app is launching from terminated). When everything finishes loading in application:didBecomeActive, I need to make sure that the rootViewController is already loaded (hence me asking about viewDidLoad) so that I can use that, via completion block, to present the applicable viewController. I just want to make sure I can do this.

Comment: You can't! That is a complete antipattern. That is what I'm telling you. You need to load the view controller _now_. Load it missing some interface if you have to, but get _out_ of the launch process's way. You have 500ms maximum and you are going way over (and a lot of that time doesn't even belong to you). Watch the videos. Start with WWDC 2018 video 803.

Comment: But I *am* loading the view controller now. I am loading the rootViewController right away. I just need to know if it is ready to perform a segue by application:didBecomeActive.

Comment: No. You know when it is ready to perform a segue because the background thread finishes doing whatever it is doing and calls you back — you, the root view controller. At that point, either the root view controller's view is in the interface (`viewDidAppear`) or it isn't. If it is, you can segue from it. You cannot "segue by application:didBecomeActive"; that's an app delegate method, there is nothing to segue from.

Comment: I was saying I needed to ask the rootViewController to perform a segue - calling this from application:didBecomeActive. So you are saying I cannot do this? Because it does work, but I guess that it is hit and miss? Basically I call, from application:didBecomeActive, a method in rootViewController that decides which segue to perform and then performs it.

Comment: You have shown _no code at all_. You have asked a purely theoretical question and then exchanged it for another purely theoretical question. All I can do is try to enunciate the principles. A phrase like "I think rootViewController needs to have loaded by that time" is a Bad Smell.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I gave the video to watch, I should have said WWDC 2018 233. It has a whole section devoted to exactly your situation: launch time when you're doing something with a database at launch. Starts at about 20:30. Watch that section, maybe several times over.

Comment: That was quite helpful. I probably will need to view it several times. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is much more to take into account during app launch than I had previously considered. I do have some serious work ahead of me. In the meantime, it seems like, at the very least, I need to put the `loadStoreWithCompletionHandler` block in a separate method and call it by `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. Even if the delay is zero, the allows the app to finish `applicationDidBecomeActive:` before the `loadStoreWithCompletionHandler` block is called. I think that is a good first step, with many more, obviously, that need to come.

Comment: Absolutely right. That is what I keep telling you. The most important thing you need to do in an app delegate method or view controller lifetime event method is _return_ from that method. That is what I mean when I keep saying _launch_. Everything you do other than return is _preventing_ launch; you need to stop doing it.

Comment: You should also watch video 407, improving app performance. It is _all about_ you. :) And it goes into great detail about launch and gives some great tips for keeping it fast and light.