# How can I programmatically control the launch image using app delegate?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there anyway to implement this loading HUD into the LaunchImage when the application first starts. The link to the progress hud is called ACProgressHUD: https://github.com/ErAbhishekChandani/ACProgressHUD

If not, is there a way to control the launch image and what it should present using the app delegate like

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
```

Ultimately I would like to implement a loading animation to the launch image, and these are just some ways I am thinking it can be done.

Comment: You cannot do this. The launch screens are displayed quickly while the app is still loading, to give the impression of being responsive. You can style them in Interface Builder but you cannot run any code. The linked answer by @the4kman above has some techniques on how to make a custom startup screen once the app has loaded and the launch screen finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. The launch screens are displayed quickly while the app is still loading, to give the impression of being responsive. You can style them in Interface Builder but you cannot run any code.

Of course you can control what happens just after this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27642016/8289095) shows some ways to do this.

---

Thanks to @the4kman for the link.